# geth sendTransaction error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value on private network

Tags: transactions, private-blockchain

I tried with all available answers converting to hex and setting different gas prices, but noting is working for me.
I am on a private network with network id : 1 and chainId = 0 
and the nodes are in sync. 
geth version is 1.7.3
please help me out

Comment: How are you sending the transactions? Mind posting some code?

Comment: @solmon Explain your problem in detail probly with logs

Comment: The setting on chainId solved my problem, i really dont understand what that means as I couldnt find any documentation of why chainId should be other than the default.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to say it all: you don't have **enough ETH in the sending account**.

Maybe you're actually trying to send from an account that has a balance of 0 ETH?